# Using within command in r to define categories

Tags: r

Say I Have the following table

```
Airbag <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"      Door  Seat 
1        0      1
2        2      0      
3        1      0     
4        0      1    
5        1      0 
6        1      0
7        0      0
8        0      0
9        0      2
10       0      0")
```

and now i introduce the variable 'ab.usage'

```
Airbag$ab.usage <- NA
```

I want to define a 'no' for cases where `Door` or `seat values = 0` or `2`

I want to define a 'yes' for cases where `Door` or `seat values = 1`

I have been tying to use `within()` command. Such that

```
within(Airbag,{
   ab.usage[Door|Seat == 0|2] <- "no"
   ab.usage[Door|Seat == 1] <- "yes"
   })
```

and also

```
within(Airbag,{
       ab.usage[Door|Seat == 0] <- "no"
       ab.usage[Door|Seat == 1] <- "yes"
       ab.usage[Door|Seat == 2] <- "no"
       })
```

But neither is changing the values of NA in `Airbag$ab.usage`.

Comment: 1. Use `ifelse`. 2. What gave you the impression that something like `Door|Seat == 0` is the correct way to specify the logical conditions? `|` needs logical values on both sides.

Comment: Do you mean `Aibag` or `Airbag`? The 1st `within` changes all `NA` values for me: `Airbag$ab.usage <- NA; Airbag <- within(Airbag,{ ab.usage[Door|Seat == 0|2] <- "no"; ab.usage[Door|Seat == 1] <- "yes" }); Airbag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the help of command `within`:

> ‘within’ is similar, except that it examines the environment after the evaluation of ‘expr’ and makes the corresponding modifications to a copy of ‘data’ (this may fail in the data frame case if objects are created which cannot be stored in a data frame), and returns it.  ‘within’ can be used as an alternative to ‘transform’.

Since a modified copy of your data frame is returned, you could just store it under a new name:

```
   Airbag.new <- within(Airbag,{
     ab.usage[Door %in% c(0, 2) | Seat %in% c(0, 2)  ] <- "no"
     ab.usage[Door == 1 | Seat == 1] <- "yes"
   })
```

I took the liberty of modifying the first proposed example, since it looked suspicious. It even looks like what is done here is that if Door = 1 or Seat = 1 but not both of them are = 1, then `ab.usage` should be 'true'. If my interpretation is correct, then a simple `xor` does the job (I used an `ifelse` as recommended by @Roland):

```
   Airbag.new <- within(Airbag,{
     ab.usage <- ifelse( xor(Door==1, Seat==1), "yes", "no")
   })
```

The result is so short that the use of `within` could easily be avoided.

Comment: You will have to be just a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the new column with `NA` values if you already know what those values are going to be, and/or how to arrive at them.  It just means more memory usage and copying.

I suggest just doing

```
Airbag$ab.usage <- with(Airbag, ifelse(Door == 1 | Seat == 1, "yes", "no"))
```